# How to dual boot existing Windows 7 laptop with Linux (Slackware distribution)?

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, multi-boot, slackware

I have a Dell laptop loaded with Windows 7.

The partitions I see looking at the Disk Manager are the following:

One ΟΕΜ partition 39MB, one NTFS partition 218.20GB (boot, page file, primary), and one recovery NTFS partition 14.65GB (system, active, primary).

I have also burnt a Slackware 14.0 DVD so that I can install the Slackware Linux distribution.

How can I make the laptop dual boot Windows 7 and Linux together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a three step solution that I suggest, after successfully adopt it myself :

1. LiveUSB creation using this link (http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=creating_the_liveusb)
   In the options use 'parted magic'.
2. Create partitions using this guide (http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=using_gparted)
3. Slackware installation based on this guide :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LA8BBS5qJ2k

Answer (score 0):

These are the exact steps I've used for installing Windows Server 2003 R2 (and Windows 7 and XP) with Slackware (versions 13.1, 14.0 and 14.1) on Dell D410, D630, D2100 and M4600 laptops. The partition sizes and numbers are based on my specific setup (C: is for Windows OS and boot partition, D: is for what-have-you, E: is the shared Windows/Linux space, and F: is the Linux OS and boot partition).

**Windows Server 2003 R2 / Slackware 14.1 dual boot**

---

**Boot Windows Install Disk**

- Create Partitions: C:(200G) D:(32G) E:(32G) F:(32G)
- Exit (F3) and reboot

**Boot Slackware Linux Installer**

Configure partitions (do not re-partition):

`fdisk /dev/sda`

- flip partition 7 (my Linux partition) type to Linux (`t` `83`)
- flag partitions 1 and 7 (Windows and Linux boot partitions) type to bootable (`a` `1` and `a` `7`)
- write and quit (`w`, `q`)

Format VFAT partitions (*do not format NTFS partition*, we'll let Windows Installer do this):

`mkfs.vfat /dev/sda5` (use NTFS if desired)

`mkfs.vfat /dev/sda6` (use NTFS if desired)

Format Linux partition:

`mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda7`

- install Linux to /dev/sda7
- lilo superblock:

Contents of lilo.conf:

```
boot = /dev/sda7
message = /boot/boot_message.txt
append = " vt.default_utf8=1"
vga = normal
image = /boot/vmlinuz
root = /dev/sda7
label = Linux
read-only
```

- Install LILO:

`lilo -C lilo.conf`

- mount /dev/sda6 to /mnt/e

`mkdir /mnt/e`

`mount -t vfat /dev/sda6 /mnt/e`

- save /dev/sda7

`dd if=/dev/sda7 of=/mnt/e/linux.bin bs=512 count=1`

`sync`

Reboot (Ctrl-Alt-Del)

**Boot Windows Install Disk**

- Install to C: drive (*do not re-partition*, use existing NTFS partition)
- Move E:\linux.bin C:\linux.bin

`attrib +hidden C:\linux.bin`

- Edit C:\boot.ini

Contents:

```
[boot loader]
timeout=30
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Windows Server 2003 Standard x64 Edition" /noexecute=optout /fastdetect
C:\linux.bin="Linux"
```